# Filter Java Servlet access with CSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, servlet-filters, content-security-policy

I need to filter the access to my servlet so it will only work in the specific frame of another website. For example, the servlet url address is this www.example.com/myservlet/home and the website address is this: www.example.com/website. Servlet should work only in the website frame and I need to close direct access to servlet ( www.example.com/myservlet/home ). Thanks Arman